# Simulating <a> href post via jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

Here is the link which works fine. It imports GMail Contacts from Google API:

**Link**

```
<a id='gmailInvite' class="button icon chat" href="<?php echo site_url('main/gmail_invite'); ?>"><span>Import GMail Contacts</span></a>
```

I am trying to repeat this functionality via `div` button.

**Div button**

```
<div class="gmailbutton" onclick="importGMailContacts()"><span class="textwhite">Import Gmail Contacts</span></a>

function importGMailContacts()
    {
      var form_data = "";
      $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('main/gmail_invite'); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: form_data,
                success: function(msg) {
                  alert(msg)
                  return true;
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                  alert(xhr.status);
                  alert(xhr.responseText);
                  alert(thrownError);
                }
        });
    }
```

When I click the div button it goes to controller method. But nothing happens.
How can I simulate `href post` from div button?

Comment: You're setting data to form_data, which is blank . . . is that intentional?

Comment: Yes. Just want to hit that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused. Clicking an A element will send a GET request, not a POST. To simulate clicking on a link, you would use `window.location = "<?php echo site_url('main/gmail_invite'); ?>"`. To send a POST that the browser follows, you'll need to create a FORM with the appropriate action and submit it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am actually tired and got confused.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the JQuery "click" function, that way you can manipulate any element and do whatever you need to do (it can be a GET, POST, or custom action). For instance, the click function can be use to submit a form, act like a "link", or simply trigger an Ajax call.

Here is the sample function:

```
$('#gmailbutton').click(function(){

var form_data = 'WHATEVER DATA YOUR COLLECTING'
$.ajax({

    //the type of call it can be GET or POST 
    type:'POST',
    //If it is a static URL you dont need to echo with PHP 
    //just write it directly
    url:'main/gmail_invite/ajax.sample.call.php', //or whatever you php file is called

    //if you want to receive the data as html,json,xml
    dataType:'json',
    cache:false,

    beforeSend:function(x){
        //use this only if the response is a JSON object    
        if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
            x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
        }       

    }
}).done(function(response){

    //use "done" rather than "success", as "success" has been deprecated from JQUERY
    console.log( response );
    //no need to return, the ajax returns the call by default

}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

    console.log( jqXHR );
    console.log( textStatus );
    console.log( errorThrown );

});
```

});